# Difficulty formatting number from DotNet program according to user's locale

Tags: locale, c#

I have been provided with a server to host my DotNet 7 application, but am having a problem display numbers formatted according to my user's locale.

The OS is:

```
$ cat os-release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.7 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.7"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.7 (Ootpa)"
...
```

My locale is:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_ZA.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_ZA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_ZA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_ZA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_ZA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_ZA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_ZA.UTF-8"
...
```

The NUMERIC settings are:

```
$ locale -k LC_NUMERIC
decimal_point="."
thousands_sep=","
grouping=3;3
numeric-decimal-point-wc=46
numeric-thousands-sep-wc=44
numeric-codeset="UTF-8"
```

So I would expect a number like `123456789.9876` formatted to the locale's numeric format to be displayed like `123,456,789.99`.

If I create the simplest program:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    const decimal d = 123456789.9876M;
    Console.WriteLine($"{d:n}");
}
```

and `dotnet run` it, it prints `123 456 789,988`.

I believe that DotNet uses [Internal Components for Unicode (ICU)](https://icu.unicode.org/), but that is a requirement for any DotNet application to run and it seems to be installed.

```
$ dnf list installed \*libicu\*
libicu.x86_64    60.3-2.el8_1    @rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
```

I am not able to force `DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=true` (e.g. in the project file) as my application requires SQL Server which does not allow an invariant culture.

The same application prints the number in the expected format on my WSL/Ubuntu instance as well as on all Windows instances I've tried.

I’ve tried [including a specific version of libicu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#app-local-icu) with the application, but it didn’t affect the formatting.

> To help application developers ensure consistency across all deployments, .NET 5 and later versions enable apps on both Windows and Unix to carry and use their own copy of ICU.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ICU.ICU4C.Runtime" Version="68.2.0.9" />
<RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.AppLocalIcu" Value="68.2.0.9" />
```

The owner of the server is security-conscious and users have the minimum rights necessary.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get my application to use the configured locale settings?

---

Outputting further information from the simple test program, it seems that the locale is correct but the LC_NUMERIC/LC_MONETARY settings used are not the same as displayed above.

```
The current culture is en-ZA
The decimal separator is ","
The group separator is " "
The decimal digits is "3"
Number formatted: 123 456 789,988
The currency symbol is "R"
The currency decimal separator is ","
The currency group separator is " "
The currency decimal digits is "2"
Currency formatted: R123 456 789,99
```

As a work-around that suits my situation I was able to force the culture-specific settings programmatically.

```cs
public static void SetCustomZAThreadCulture(bool linuxOnly = true) {
    if (!linuxOnly || CrossPlatform.IsLinux()) {
        CultureInfo customCultureInfo = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        customCultureInfo.NumberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo {
            NumberDecimalSeparator = ".",
            NumberGroupSeparator = ",",
            NumberDecimalDigits = 2,
            CurrencySymbol = "R",
            CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".",
            CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",",
            CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2,
        };
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = customCultureInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about `dotnet`, but in `php`, `python3`  I always had to explicitly set french locale (`LC_TIME`'s value for weekday and month name)